# Unity 3D Game Crashing On Windows Phone 8 Build

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine

I am developing a Unity game for Windows Phone. It is a 3D Flappy Bird game, but relatively small and lowest quality for everything. My problem is is that when I build it to my phone (I don't have Hyper-v for some reason, so no emulators. I'm on Windows 8.1. I built it to a Lumia 925) it displays the menus and when it loads the main game, it exits. Here is the code on the Output:

"The program '[2940] TaskHost.exe' has exited with code -2147483645 (0x80000003)."

It also says something to do with "Access Violation".

It also works fine on my PC.

It used to work fine on my phone, but now it just exits after the Unity logo. I have built a few other games, some of which are 3D and are massive, but they work fine. I would really like this error solved, as I have spent a long time on this game.

-Dear rene,
I know what you edited.

Answer (score 0):

Did you just move up to 4.5?

I had the same issue.  My app worked before but now (after migrating up to 4.5) it crashes after displaying the logo with the same error you listed.  I fired up 4.3, rebuilt the app, redeployed it and it ran perfectly.  Hopefully you also migrated to 4.5 and simply re-downloading 4.3 will get you back in action.